# Why isn't get_option array contents displaying?

Tags: options

I've been to countless posts looking for the answer to this and have tried nearly every combination.  So obviously, I'm missing a step so small that it's likely unfathomable to the Wordpress community.

My code writes the options to the database, but fails to display them back.  The array is NOT set.  Multiple options can be added and deleted.

Writes the data:

```
<?php
     $mycontents = array('content' => $_POST['cont'], 'content2' => $_POST['cont2']);
     update_option('slider_contents',$mycontents);
?>
```

Here are the database entries:

```
a:2:{s:7:"content";a:3:{i:0;s:19:"This is content 1-a";i:1;s:19:"This is content 2-a";i:2;s:19:"This is content 3-a";}s:8:"content2";a:3:{i:0;s:19:"This is content 1-b";i:1;s:19:"This is content 2-b";i:2;s:19:"This is content 3-b";}}
```

Trying to read and display the data:

```
<?php
    $the_contents=get_option('slider_contents');
    foreach ($the_contents as $content) {
         $content1=stripslashes($content->content);
         $content2=stripslashes($content->content2);
?>
<li><textarea name="cont[]" rows="3" style="width:70%;" ><?php echo $content1; ?></textarea><br><textarea name="cont2[]" rows="3" style="width:70%;" ><?php echo $content2; ?></textarea><br><input type="button" value="Delete this option" onClick="delete_field(this);"  /><input type="button" value="Add new option" onClick="add_to_field(this);"  /></li>

        <?php } ?>
```

I've also tried...

```
<?php
    $the_contents=get_option('slider_contents');
    foreach ($the_contents as $content) {
         $content1=stripslashes($content['content']);
         $content2=stripslashes($content['content2']);
?>
```

The output of `var_dump($the_contents);` is :

```
array(2) { 
  ["content"]=> array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(19) "This is content 1-a" 
    [1]=> string(19) "This is content 2-a" 
    [2]=> string(19) "This is content 3-a" 
  } 
  ["content2"]=> array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(19) "This is content 1-b" 
    [1]=> string(19) "This is content 2-b" 
    [2]=> string(19) "This is content 3-b" 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Add `var_dump($the_contents);` immediately after your `get_option` line and paste the output into your question, please.

Comment: array(2) { ["content"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(19) "This is content 1-a" [1]=> string(19) "This is content 2-a" [2]=> string(19) "This is content 3-a" } ["content2"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(19) "This is content 1-b" [1]=> string(19) "This is content 2-b" [2]=> string(19) "This is content 3-b" } }

Comment: ***"... and paste the output into your question"*** Formatting in comments is minimal making anything besides ordinary language content hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your code. Your first code block is treating an array like an object so your second attempt is closer to accurate:

```
$the_contents=get_option('slider_contents');
// var_dump($the_content);
foreach ($the_contents as $content) {
     $content1=stripslashes($content['content']);
     $content2=stripslashes($content['content2']);
```

Assuming you did what I suggested and placed the `var_dump` where I have in that code block, then what is happening is this: `foreach ($the_contents as $content) {` lets you loop through the array. At each iteration, `$content` is itself an array that looks like:

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(19) "This is content 1-a" 
    [1]=> string(19) "This is content 2-a" 
    [2]=> string(19) "This is content 3-a" 
}
```

So when you try to access `$content['content']` you are trying to access a key that doesn't exist-- you've already looped "past" that. You can demonstrate this for yourself by running:

```
$the_contents = unserialize('a:2:{s:7:"content";a:3:{i:0;s:19:"This is content 1-a";i:1;s:19:"This is content 2-a";i:2;s:19:"This is content 3-a";}s:8:"content2";a:3:{i:0;s:19:"This is content 1-b";i:1;s:19:"This is content 2-b";i:2;s:19:"This is content 3-b";}}');
foreach ($the_contents as $content) {
  var_dump($content); 
}
```

What you need to be doing is looping over that `$contents` array and taking each piece individually.

```
foreach ($the_contents as $content) { // this part you already have
  foreach ($content as $c) {
    echo stripslashes($c);
    // you are building a string, of course, but that is the idea
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  This certainly looks the way to go, but I'm thinking I may not be formulating my array correctly to begin with.  Lets say I have 5 options per record (rather than 2). Would I need to do 5 stacked foreach loops?  Should I format my update_option array differently instead?  I'm at the start of making a simple slider-type plugin where I can add as many slides as I wish.  Each slide has 5-6 attributes occupying one record (color, header, text, etc).  These attributes will be occupying content, content1, etc.

Comment: You would only need 5 nested loops if you have nested arrays that deep, and if you do you should probably at least consider doing it differently. You might be better off starting another question to ask that. It is really a pretty different question. I am not sure the question would be WordPress specific (this one is questionable, honestly), though, so maybe [so]

Comment: @NickYoung : not with that array. Try it.